# Adobe Illustrator expanded objects not generating image map code.

Tags: html, polygon, imagemap, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to create an imagemap using the adobe illustrator attribute tools. I was following the ministeps from [How to get the path coordinates of a shape for use with image-maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845958/how-to-get-the-path-coordinates-of-a-shape-for-use-with-image-maps/13847787#13847787) here, but now illustrator is not generating the image map code. It refuses to add any image map code at the moment. I believe the reason is because I expanded the various objects. I'm wondering if I can get a polygon image map with illustrator.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CFZQ.png

Current code result

```
<html>
<head>
<title>map1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- ImageReady Slices (map1.ai) -->
<img src="images/map1.png" width="1200" height="850" alt="">
<!-- End ImageReady Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save it as an SVG.

See: http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/creating-an-image-map-from-svg/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me - I used an svg from adobe illustrator, but it seems to give me incorrect points and I'm not sure why. I've tried importing it and resaving it with inkscape, that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: If you're going this way, do make sure you check if older IE versions will show an SVG image...